# How to add a Flatpak's app to Gnome 3 auto-starts?

Tags: gnome3, unity, autostart, flatpak

I installed telegram-desktop via Flatpak and would like to auto start the messenger when logging into Gnome 3 (or Unity as a fact). Is there a way to robustly do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting from the answer given by @intika I found a solution I like more.

Instead of replicating the content of the existing desktop-file in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.telegram.desktop.desktop` I linked it inside my personal `~/.config/autostart/`. Works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 14):

**Auto start x applications:**

One way to make an application auto start at user login is to add its `.desktop` file to `/etc/xdg/autostart/` this will affect all users

Just copy or link (`ln -s`) your `telegram.desktop` to `/etc/xdg/autostart/` if you don't have a `telegram.desktop` create a new one, here is an example with Deepin Music Flatpak's package

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Exec=flatpak run com.deepin.Music
GenericName=
Icon=deepin-music
MimeType=
Name=Deepin Music
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Categories=Music;
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
```

Answer (score 6):

- Press <kbd>Super</kbd>
- Select "Startup applications"
- Select "Add"
- Enter

  - "Name": `Telegram`
  - "Command": `/usr/bin/flatpak run org.telegram.desktop`
- Click "Save"

Comment: BEST SOLUTION. Also for Skype we can use >> usr/bin/flatpak run com.skype.Client

Answer (score 0):

Commands for Telegram and Skype in any Startup application managers:

- `flatpak run org.telegram.desktop`
- `flatpak run com.skype.Client`

Comment: `/usr/bin/flatpak` rather than `flatpak`